# Blender crashes when baking and rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, uv, export

I have Blender 2.8 and it crashes everytime I try to bake or render.
I tried importing my texture into Marvelous Designer to edit it, but it crashes.
I think there's a trouble with UV Map, because when I export it as an .obj into Marvelous Designer, it crashes and says it can't recognize UV borders. 
And I don't see what it can be.

Can anyone please help?

Here's the blend file if someone can find the problem :

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Could you use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach your blend file? This way it won't expire. Thx.

Comment: Just did, thanks!

Comment: Opening your file does not crash on me. I had to recreate a material because the one present in the file by default for the "sweater" object seems completely empty (named "DiffuseMap"). Also I had to switch to Cycles instead of Eevee. After that and creating a new texture, I was able to bake "color" without any problem. I am running 2.83.8 on Mac using CPU only though...

Comment: Just tried, and now bake is stuck at 0%.. Any idea?

Comment: what's your baking texture size? Try with a small one like 1024x1024

Comment: It's 1024x1024. I tried debugging, it says there's a problem with the UV mapping.